# Touchpad tab is missing but ubuntu detects

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, synaptics

i have installed ubuntu 12.04 but when i got to mouse settings, touchpad tab is missing. Ubuntu detects it.

```
shahzeb@shahzeb-laptop:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Webcam                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys     

                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I am using HP Dv6.
Kindly help me, i shall be thankful.

Comment: I have the same problem here. mine's Aspire One d255 and my touchpad tab in the settings is missing too. It was well a while back and it's now gone.

Answer (score 2):

There might be something wrong with your driver.

Check if `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is installed.

or do the following:

1. Enable SHMConfig
  - Change the value for **SHMConfig** to **true** by editing the **50-synaptics.conf** file.
    ```
    /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
    ```
    // It might look like this:
    ```
    Section "InputClass"
         Identifier "touchpad catchall"
         Driver "synaptics"
         MatchIsTouchpad "on"
         MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
               Option "TapButton1" "1"
               Option "TapButton2" "2"
               Option "TapButton3" "3"
               Option "SHMConfig"  "true"
    EndSection
    ```
  - or
  - Open a terminal and type:
    ```
    synclient SHMConfig=1
    ```
2. Install **gsynaptics** from the universe repository.